# Get nodes from LENGTH(r)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This code

```
MATCH (n { name: 'Create node' })<-[r*]-(s { name: ';' }) 
WITH n,s, LENGTH(r) AS depth 
RETURN n,s, depth
```

will return [image] the number of relationships between first and last nodes. Is it possible to get the nodes that are in between those relationships?

*Bonus question: is it possible to get them in order?*

http://console.neo4j.org/r/z1iafh

(this code does not work in console, only on localhost. query to create nodes

```
create 
(_0  {name:"CREATE"}),
(_1  {name:"("}),
(_2  {name:"node_name"}),
(_3  {name:")"}),
(_4  {name:";"}),
_1-[:CREATE_NODE_COMMAND]->_0,
_2-[:CREATE_NODE_COMMAND]->_1,
_3-[:CREATE_NODE_COMMAND]->_2,
_4-[:CREATE_NODE_COMMAND]->_3
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could augment your match statement to match the entire path from **n** to **s** and then you could use the `nodes` function on the path to return the collection of nodes in order (from n to s).  If you want just the nodes between the start and end nodes you could return the collection form the second to the second last only.

```
MATCH p=(n { name: 'Create node' })<-[r*]-(s { name: ';' }) 
WITH n,s, size(r) as depth, length(p) as depth2, nodes(p) as nodes 
RETURN n,s, depth, depth2, nodes[1..length(nodes)-1]
```

`size()` can be used to return the number of elements in a collection whereas `length()` should only be used to return the length of a path or a string. Its use on other objects (collections and patterns) may be deprecated in future neo4j versions; currently supported for backwards compatibility.